# How to stop a method from starting until JFrame is closed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane

I am using both JFrame and JOption pane, the beginning of my main method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   welcomeScreen();
   int input = getInput();
```

where welcomeScreen calls an object extending JFrame and getInput uses JOptionPane like this:

```
String s = "blah blah"
String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(s);
return data;
```

When you run the program both JOption pane and JFrame open at the same time but I only want the JFrame which is called first in the main method to open and I want the JOptionPane to open after I close the JFrame via the JButton implementing the actionListener:

```
public class close implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aL) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

How do i do this?

Comment: don't use `system.exit();` call `dispose()`

Comment: you can open joption frame after call  `dispose()` .why do you call from main method?

Comment: how do I tell it to open JOptionPane after I call dispose? @FastSnail

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)? Use a modal dialog instead of a `JFrame`, also make sure you're executing your code from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, or strange things start to happen. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: @John314 call your `joption method` after `system.exit` line  .but `system.exit` should replace with `dispose()`

Answer (score 1):

You may add a WindowListener to your frame, so when it detects the actions of closing the frame, it will run the codes you implement in the overridden `windowClosing()` method. You may do something like this:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        frame.dispose();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("your message");
    }
});
```

Comment: @John314 Take a look at my solution.